# Chart.Series throws a NullReference Exception

Tags: c#, charts

I have a problem that I have not been able to solve by searching the answers on this forum. The line `if (videoChart.Series != null)` is throwing a null reference exception.
The problem seems to be the function get_Series in the charting class. videoChart is a C# Chart class object.

```
    if (videoChart != null)
    {
         if (videoChart.Series != null)
         {
               videoChart.Series.Clear();
         }

         if (videoChart.Annotations != null)
         {
               videoChart.Annotations.Clear();
    }
```

Help please.

Comment: You might want to share `get_Series` function and all the relevant code related to Chart binding.

Comment: The get_Series function is internal to Microsoft's charting class and is not of my writing. It is the top most line when I click 'View details' on the Exception dialog which appears at run time.

Comment: How do you fill the data into videoChart object?

Comment: That is rarther complex involving threads. But why is that relevant? Either the collection is empty or it is not. Why is it not that simple?

Comment: The series are added a batch at a time. The error occurs when I kill the current thread adding the batches and then start it again (when I want to clear what was already added). Could this cause problems?

Comment: Unless you set it to null neither the Series nor the Annotations of a valid Chart can be null. Empty (Count = 0) yes but never null. So your code is nonsense anyway. But if it throws you have not a valid chart. Probably you have just __declared__ it but not __created__ it. `Chart videoChart;` vs. `Chart videoChart = new Chart();`